# How to get wxWidgets working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, wxwidgets

I've got a problem for which I would very much like a solution please:

All I'm trying to do is use wxWidgets in Visual Studio 2012 (in C++), and make it accessible to my code project.  That shouldn't be so hard, should it?  But as usual, even though there are programming tutorials for it, wxWidgets is evidently one of those things that has no proper documentation just to simply get it running, or if it does then I sure can't find it.

I downloaded the installer for Windows and installed it.  When it finished, it gave me a message that said:

wxWidgets was installed successfully!

Please note: before using wxWidgets in your application,
you must build the library using the same compiler you
use for building your program.

Please see docs/msw/install.md file in the installation
directory for the detailed instructions about how to build
wxWidgets and use it from your application.

It should be noted that I think I remember something on the website or somewhere saying that I can just include a header file into my project and forego the DLL altogether (which is what I'd prefer to do, if possible), though I may possibly be misremembering that or confusing it with something else.

Anyway, when I opened the docs/msw/install.md file, I found (amongst other things) these instructions:

--- From the IDE

Ready to use project files are provided for VC++ versions 8, 9,
10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16 and 17 (also known as MSVS 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012,
2013, 2015, 2017, 2019 and 2022 respectively).

Simply open `wx_vcN.sln` (for N=8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16 or 17) file,
select the appropriate configuration (Debug or Release, static or DLL)
and build the solution. Notice that when building a DLL configuration,
you may need to perform the build several times because the projects
are not always built in the correct order, and this may result in link
errors. Simply do the build again, up to 3 times, to fix this.

Of course, it doesn't even say WHERE the "wx_vcN.sln" files are, but I ran a file search and found them in C:\wxWidgets-3.1.6\build\msw and I opened the one called wx_vc11.sln, because that seems to be the one that corresponds to VS2012, right?

Anyway, it took a LONG time to load, because it had to keep scanning through thousands of files and so forth, but when it was finally finished, I did the "Rebuild All" command thrice in a row, like it says to do (which also took a while).

But I'm not sure where it even put the actual DLL file.  It says that it's in C:\wxWidgets-3.1.6\build\msw....\lib\vc_lib\wxmsw31ud_xrc.lib, but where the hell is "...."?  It doesn't even bother to specify the entire path!  What kind of nonsense is that?!  I just want the file so that I can put it into my project!  Or better yet, just a .h file that takes care of everything would be great.  Supposedly there's one to include called "wx/wx.h", which then includes everything else, I think, but I don't know if that one indirectly also requires a DLL.

I always have problems with DLLs, anyway, though I'll use one if I absolutely have to.  You'd think it would be the easiest thing to import a DLL into a project, but for some reason, I've never been able to find any sort of tutorial that explains a specific, step-by-step way to do it which is guaranteed to work, so on the rare occasion that I actually need to use a DLL (99% of the time I can just rely on my own code and the .h files included with Visual Studio), I always end up muddling through it until it FINALLY works by sheer accident (if I'm lucky).  Mostly, it just reports errors for one reason or another, that it's not properly included or compatible, or that the header files that I'm using which reference it keep showing the same errors, as though I hadn't even imported the DLL file at all!  I've been programming for about 30 years, and I work on things like AI and compression and cryptographic algorithms.  I don't say this to brag, but to point out that if someone as experienced as me has trouble getting a DLL to attach properly to a roject, then there's something severely wrong with the whole process, or the documentation for it!  I HATE using DLLS, because it's always a HUGE chore, but I'll do it if there's absolutely no other way (though I'd appreciate step-by-step instructions, if you don't mind).

But enough about that.  In any case, I have an example project in which wxWidgets is being used in conjunction with Vulkan, and though it has compilation errors (because Vulkan didn't properly install on my machine (when I try to run the sample programs it says they're missing DLLs - big surprise) and as it turns out, I don't think it's compatible with my video card, anyway (which might possibly be why it didn't install properly), so I think I'll have to resort to OpenGL instead - PLEASE tell me that's compatible with wxWidgets!), but even in that example project, it has errors where it's trying to include and use wxWidgets stuff (like "wx/wx.h"), even though that's supposed to be a complete and already working project!  I can't find any DLL files or the header files in question anywhere in the project directories!

So anyway, there's got to be an easier way to get this all set up, just to the point that I can make a simple test program using wxWidgets, and compile it.  I'd REALLY like to be able to get at least that much working sometime tomorrow morning, so I'd greatly appreciate any help you can give me!  Thank you.

Comment: Could you distil this into a single question?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I know the fustration with setting up libraries, but could you please edit to cut out   those part? So we can help you better

Comment: But that's basically the problem.  In summary, I need to get wxWidgets to work in VS2012 C++, ideally by just including a .h file, otherwise with a DLL file, but almost everything that I described above just explains what I tried and what went wrong (and some of it was stuff that I copied/pasted to show a message which was displayed and something that I read in an instructional file).  Basically, what it boils down to is that I just want to be able to get a test project up and running, and then I can take it from there.  Also I mentioned how I'd really like to get it compatible with OpenGL.

Comment: Why would I have to do that?  It says that what it provides is compatible with VS2012 C++.

Comment: ***But I'm not sure where it even put the actual DLL file. It says that it's in C:\wxWidgets-3.1.6\build\msw....\lib\vc_lib\wxmsw31ud_xrc.lib, but where the hell is "...."?*** I think the reason for the ... here is it will be a different folder for each msvc version and they did not want to list all 9 choices.

Comment: Oh, I guess I thought it would show the exact path that it used in my specific instance, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

@ThisIsMe,
First of all you need to educate yourself on properly using C++.

When you acquire the C++ code it contains of 2 portion - `header file` and `source code`.

Header file is what you call a declaration you declare you classes there - class name, member variable and method.

In the source files You define what you declared and you put an actual code there.

Now with that in mind:

wxWidgets contains both header and source files. When you downloaded the installer and did the installation it just copied the "text file" (headers and sources) into the folder of you choice.

Now as you can imagine text files are not executable - you need to compile them into the binary files And that is exactly what you did. (I don't know why you did it 3 times though - I guess you got an errors after building 1st and 2nd time).

Now, you said you have a project that (either uses wxWidgets or you want to incorporate wxWidgets into - which one is it, BTW?). The answer to this question will help direct you to a proper solution.

Now, you said that you tried the Vulkan and it fails to run the demo. How did it fails? Did it produce an error? What was it? Did it even run?

Now wxWidgets does support OpenGL as can be seen by looking at the documentation and checking the different samples that comes with the library, but I'm just curious if what you are seeing from Vulkan is really an incompatibility with the Video Card.

So, we need you to answer the questions I put and so we can help you further. Just keep in mind - C++ is not for the beginner programmers and if you are struggling with understanding the difference between compilation, installation , headers and sources - it will be very hard for you.

Maybe you should start with something simpler - like wxPython and forget about C++ for now.

Comment: Well, I appreciate your help, but you must not have read where I said that I've been programming for 30 years, and using C++ for more than 20, so I really wouldn't say that I'm a "beginner".  In any case, I understand the difference between a header and source file, but I've seen times when all of the code was put into a single header file so that I could just include it (like SQLite, for example), and it's extremely convenient.  The reason I compiled thrice is because the instructions said to do so (see my original post), which seemed odd to me as well.

Comment: I suspect Vulkan may not be compatible with my card because after installing it and trying to run a test program, it said it was missing a DLL, and I then read something that says it may not be compatible with older cards (that one was made in 2013).  I'm not sure I understand the distinction in your question, where you afterwards ask, "which one is it, BTW?".

Comment: @ThisIsMe, the instruction said: "you may need to perform the build several times because the projects are not always built in the correct order, and this may result in link errors". Hence the question if you got any errors after the first build. But that's fine - just a note for the future.

Comment: @ThisIsMe, SQLite implementation does not have one header file - it has header file and a C file (I know because I use it in my project). Now, I don't think any such a big project will have just one header file which will contain everything - declaration and definition of the code. I would be surprised if something like this ever exist.

Comment: @ThisIsMe, it is of course possible that Vulkan does not support the card. But what I wonder is - what happen when you run Vulkan demo? Does it give you an error? If yes - what is the `EXACT` error message?

Comment: @ThisIsMe, As far as I understand - if you can't work with Vulkan, you will start a brand new project based on OpenGL and wxWidgets, right? And if you can run Vulkan, you will just use an existing project. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: The version of SQLite that I use has just a header file, I promise.  I don't know why, or how it's different than yours, but that's how it is for me.  I may have gotten it from some GitHub.  I don't remember the exact Vulkan error, and it's not on this computer so I don't have it right now, but I know that it was missing a DLL, and this is right after I installed it.  It might be a compatibility issue or something else - I don't really know.  But yes, I'll try to use Vulkan and if that fails then I'll use OpenGL.  In either case, it's a new project with wxWidgets.

Comment: @ThisIsMe, please try to make a Vulkan running. As you said - it has a demo or sample project that don't use wxWidgets. Run it and see if itproduces any errors. Tell us if it produces any errors. (no wxWidgets - just a Vulkan). In any case - I doubt that Vulkan will not support the old hardware. In regards to SQLite - you probably have it installed as compiled binary and just include the header file and link to the library.. But that's irrelevant to the problem at hand...

Comment: I'll see if I can get it running tomorrow morning when I do the rest of this.  I'll tell you if there's a specific error.  In any case, Vulkan (or OpenGL) is just something that I want to eventually get running to use with wxWidgets, but it's not an immediate concern - it's just that I wanted to make sure that it's at least compatible.  In any case, I think I might have a way to at least get wxWidgets working, but I'll be trying all of this tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ThisIsMe, do not try. There is a very simple solution for that. Inside the MSVC open the filewxWidgets\samples\opengl\pyramid\pyramid_vc9.sln. Build and run it. If it runs - great. If not - you card is not compatible with the latest version of OpenGL, You should then open wxWidgets\samples\opengl\cube\cube_vc9.sln, build and run it. After it is successful - open project properties and check the C/C++ Include and Linker properties for the project.. Do the same in you project and you will be good to go.

Comment: Alsdo, check the code for the samples - it will give you a clue what is needed in order to have OpenGL working with wxWidgets.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll still try for Vulkan, but it will be nice to have OpenGL as an option too.